# How to trigger event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, events, triggers, addeventlistener, dom-events

I have attached an event to a text box using `addEventListener`. It works fine. My problem arose when I wanted to trigger the event programmatically from another function.

How can I do it?

Comment: Please change the accepted answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20548330/3853934), it's more up-to-date.

Comment: @RickyStam It looks like that MDN article [moved to here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

Answer (score 521, accepted):

Note: the [initEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent) method is now deprecated. Other answers feature up-to-date and recommended practice.

---

You can use [fireEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536423%28VS.85%29.aspx) on **IE 8** or lower, and W3C's [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent) on *most* other browsers. To create the event you want to fire, you can use either `createEvent` or `createEventObject` depending on the browser.

Here is a self-explanatory piece of code (from prototype) that fires an event `dataavailable` on an `element`:

```
var event; // The custom event that will be created
if(document.createEvent){
    event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    event.initEvent("dataavailable", true, true);
    event.eventName = "dataavailable";
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
} else {
    event = document.createEventObject();
    event.eventName = "dataavailable";
    event.eventType = "dataavailable";
    element.fireEvent("on" + event.eventType, event);
}
```

Comment: Dont't forget that only the IE version has the 'on' in front (I missed that at first)

Comment: What does the variable `eventName` contain here?

Comment: @Alsciende how can I attach my event handler to this custom event?

Comment: `dataavailable` should be in the `eventName` variable I believe.

Comment: Yep dataavailable should be in eventName and memo should be defined too (define to {} is ok).

Comment: I think the question is: where does eventName come from? In this code it is undefined. Should it be "dataavailable"? If so, please edit the answer.

Comment: Internet Explorer 9+ handles createEvent and dispatchEvent, so there is no need for those if statements.

Comment: This example doesn't even works, see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20548330/407213

Comment: I am confused on whether this is a cross-browser technique. Is it?

Comment: fireEvent on IE what verison of IE it supports?

Comment: Looks like the process for creating custom events might change at some point - see the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) for more details. But for now this answer worked fine for me, so thanks!

Comment: The last lines have to call `document.dispatchEvent` and `document.fireEvent` respectively.

Comment: `document.createEvent` seems to be deprecated in favor of `new Event`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent

Comment: does not work on ie11 via virtualbox on mac host: https://github.com/lingtalfi/browsers-behaviours/blob/master/listeners-execution-order/listeners.md

Comment: or: $(selector).change();

Comment: @CiroSantilli郝海东冠状病六四事件法轮功 [Document.createEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent) isn’t deprecated, but Event.initEvent() is, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent).

Answer (score 432):

A working example:

```
// Add an event listener
document.addEventListener("name-of-event", function(e) {
  console.log(e.detail); // Prints "Example of an event"
});

// Create the event
var event = new CustomEvent("name-of-event", { "detail": "Example of an event" });

// Dispatch/Trigger/Fire the event
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

For older browsers [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent#Polyfill) and more complex examples, see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent).

See support tables for [`EventTarget.dispatchEvent`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dispatchevent) and [`CustomEvent`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=customevent).

Comment: One thing to add: if there should be a know-typed event (like [TransitionEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TransitionEvent), [ClipboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent), etc) the appropriate constructor could be called.

Comment: Won't work with any version of IE (https://caniuse.com/#feat=customevent). See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49117631/165673) for a fix.

Comment: Note to future readers, `detail` is a property of the `Event`, so assign any data you want to access at the other end to it and access by `event.detail`. +1

Answer (score 185):

If you don't want to use jQuery and aren't especially concerned about backwards compatibility, just use:

```
let element = document.getElementById(id);
element.dispatchEvent(new Event("change")); // or whatever the event type might be
```

See the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event).

**EDIT:** Depending on your setup you might want to add `bubbles: true`:

```
let element = document.getElementById(id);
element.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { 'bubbles': true }));
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it doesn't use deprecated methods like initEvent()

Comment: Nice solution, but be aware this will not work on IE11. You should then use `CustomEvent` and the according polyfill.

Answer (score 54):

if you use jQuery, you can simple do

```
$('#yourElement').trigger('customEventName', [arg0, arg1, ..., argN]);
```

and handle it with

```
$('#yourElement').on('customEventName',
   function (objectEvent, [arg0, arg1, ..., argN]){
       alert ("customEventName");
});
```

where "[arg0, arg1, ..., argN]" means that these args are optional.

Answer (score 30):

Note: the [initCustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/initCustomEvent) method is now deprecated. Other answers feature up-to-date and recommended practice.

---

If you are supporting IE9+ the you can use the following. The same concept is incorporated in [You Might Not Need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

```js
function addEventListener(el, eventName, handler) {
  if (el.addEventListener) {
    el.addEventListener(eventName, handler);
  } else {
    el.attachEvent('on' + eventName, function() {
      handler.call(el);
    });
  }
}

function triggerEvent(el, eventName, options) {
  var event;
  if (window.CustomEvent) {
    event = new CustomEvent(eventName, options);
  } else {
    event = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
    event.initCustomEvent(eventName, true, true, options);
  }
  el.dispatchEvent(event);
}

// Add an event listener.
addEventListener(document, 'customChangeEvent', function(e) {
  document.body.innerHTML = e.detail;
});

// Trigger the event.
triggerEvent(document, 'customChangeEvent', {
  detail: 'Display on trigger...'
});
```

---

If you are already using jQuery, here is the jQuery version of the code above.

```js
$(function() {
  // Add an event listener.
  $(document).on('customChangeEvent', function(e, opts) {
    $('body').html(opts.detail);
  });

  // Trigger the event.
  $(document).trigger('customChangeEvent', {
    detail: 'Display on trigger...'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This will not work for any version of IE, as a `window.CustomEvent` exists but it cannot be called as a constructor: http://caniuse.com/#search=CustomEvent ;)

Answer (score 15):

I searched for firing click, mousedown and mouseup event on mouseover using JavaScript. I found an answer provided by [Juan Mendes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227299/juan-mendes). For the answer click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click).

Click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/rHMCy/4/) is the live demo and below is the code:

```
function fireEvent(node, eventName) {
    // Make sure we use the ownerDocument from the provided node to avoid cross-window problems
    var doc;
    if (node.ownerDocument) {
        doc = node.ownerDocument;
    } else if (node.nodeType == 9) {
        // the node may be the document itself, nodeType 9 = DOCUMENT_NODE
        doc = node;
    } else {
        throw new Error("Invalid node passed to fireEvent: " + node.id);
    }

    if (node.dispatchEvent) {
        // Gecko-style approach (now the standard) takes more work
        var eventClass = "";

        // Different events have different event classes.
        // If this switch statement can't map an eventName to an eventClass,
        // the event firing is going to fail.
        switch (eventName) {
        case "click": // Dispatching of 'click' appears to not work correctly in Safari. Use 'mousedown' or 'mouseup' instead.
        case "mousedown":
        case "mouseup":
            eventClass = "MouseEvents";
            break;

        case "focus":
        case "change":
        case "blur":
        case "select":
            eventClass = "HTMLEvents";
            break;

        default:
            throw "fireEvent: Couldn't find an event class for event '" + eventName + "'.";
            break;
        }
        var event = doc.createEvent(eventClass);

        var bubbles = eventName == "change" ? false : true;
        event.initEvent(eventName, bubbles, true); // All events created as bubbling and cancelable.

        event.synthetic = true; // allow detection of synthetic events
        // The second parameter says go ahead with the default action
        node.dispatchEvent(event, true);
    } else if (node.fireEvent) {
        // IE-old school style
        var event = doc.createEventObject();
        event.synthetic = true; // allow detection of synthetic events
        node.fireEvent("on" + eventName, event);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer didn’t work for me, none of the createEvent ones did.

What worked for me in the end was:

```
targetElement.dispatchEvent(
    new MouseEvent('click', {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        view: window,
}));
```

Here’s a snippet:

```js
const clickBtn = document.querySelector('.clickme');
const viaBtn = document.querySelector('.viame');

viaBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    clickBtn.dispatchEvent(
        new MouseEvent('click', {
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true,
            view: window,
    }));
});

clickBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.warn(`I was accessed via the other button! A ${event.type} occurred!`);
});
```

```html
<button class="clickme">Click me</button>

<button class="viame">Via me</button>
```

From reading:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent

Answer (score 10):

Modified @Dorian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20548330/165673) to work with IE:

```
document.addEventListener("my_event", function(e) {
  console.log(e.detail);
});

var detail = 'Event fired';

try {

    // For modern browsers except IE:
    var event = new CustomEvent('my_event', {detail:detail});

} catch(err) {

  // If IE 11 (or 10 or 9...?) do it this way:

    // Create the event.
    var event = document.createEvent('Event');
    // Define that the event name is 'build'.
    event.initEvent('my_event', true, true);
    event.detail = detail;

}

// Dispatch/Trigger/Fire the event
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

**FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/z6zom9d0/1/

**SEE ALSO:**
https://caniuse.com/#feat=customevent

Comment: in your comment "For modern browsers except IE" I guess "except IE" is redundant ;)

Comment: May I ask why global `var` and not local `let` and `const`? The code may fail on second call even.

Answer (score 8):

Just to suggest an alternative that does not involve the need to manually invoke a listener event:

Whatever your event listener does, move it into a function and call that function from the event listener.

Then, you can also call that function anywhere else that you need to accomplish the same thing that the event does when it fires.

I find this less "code intensive" and easier to read.

Comment: What if you want to do multiple different things for the same event (or well, callback function in your case) depending on context? :) It's a good alternative but this feels more like a comment than an answer as the OP wants to know how to programmatically trigger an event as opposed to using a callback :)

Comment: You are quite right that this should have been a comment rather than an answer.  Why?  Because, uhm, well, .... it doesn't answer the question that was actually asked.  Good call.  As to your own question, I'd say this would be a great opportunity for constructors in JavaScript!  ;-)  But without them, I'd say, send an argument with your function call and let that be used to determine what the function should do.

Answer (score 6):

I just used the following (seems to be much simpler):

```
element.blur();
element.focus();
```

In this case the event is triggered only if value was really changed just as you would trigger it by normal focus locus lost performed by user.

Comment: This does not take into account what kind of event it is.  Blurring and focusing may trigger the event but it may not as well. This is inviting bugs.

Comment: This also applies to `element.click()`.

Comment: This fixed a weird issue for my  Angular/Cordova app, in Android, where the textarea would refuse to clear itself. So thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
function fireMouseEvent(obj, evtName) {
    if (obj.dispatchEvent) {
        //var event = new Event(evtName);
        var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        event.initMouseEvent(evtName, true, true, window,
                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        obj.dispatchEvent(event);
    } else if (obj.fireEvent) {
        event = document.createEventObject();
        event.button = 1;
        obj.fireEvent("on" + evtName, event);
        obj.fireEvent(evtName);
    } else {
        obj[evtName]();
    }
}

var obj = document.getElementById("......");
fireMouseEvent(obj, "click");
```

Comment: This is deprecated. Only useful for polyfills. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent

Answer (score 2):

What's worth noticing, is the fact that we can create, any kind of pre-defined events, and listen to it from anywhere.

[We are not limited to classical built-in events.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

In this base example, a custom event `interfacebuiltsuccessuserdefinedevent` is dispatched every 3 seconds, on the `self.document`

```js
self.document.addEventListener('interfacebuiltsuccessuserdefinedevent', () => console.log("WOW"), false)

setInterval(() => {  // Test
  self.document.dispatchEvent(new Event('interfacebuiltsuccessuserdefinedevent')) 
}, 3000 ) // Test
```

Interesting fact: `elements` can listen for events that haven't been created yet.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to call the very same function that has been registered with `addEventListener` directly.

You can also trigger a fake event with `CustomEvent` and co.

Finally some elements such as `<input type="file">` support a `.click()` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn-test');
var event = new Event(null);

event.initEvent('beforeinstallprompt', true, true);
btn.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', null, false);
btn.dispatchEvent(event);
```

this will imediattely trigger an event *'beforeinstallprompt'*

Answer (score 0):

You could use this function i compiled together.

```
if (!Element.prototype.trigger)
  {
    Element.prototype.trigger = function(event)
    {
        var ev;

        try
        {
            if (this.dispatchEvent && CustomEvent)
            {
                ev = new CustomEvent(event, {detail : event + ' fired!'});
                this.dispatchEvent(ev);
            }
            else
            {
                throw "CustomEvent Not supported";
            }
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            if (document.createEvent)
            {
                ev = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
                ev.initEvent(event, true, true);

                this.dispatchEvent(event);
            }
            else
            {
                ev = document.createEventObject();
                ev.eventType = event;
                this.fireEvent('on'+event.eventType, event);
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Trigger an event below:

```
var dest = document.querySelector('#mapbox-directions-destination-input');
dest.trigger('focus');
```

Watch Event:

```
dest.addEventListener('focus', function(e){
   console.log(e);
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: May I ask what's the purpose of throwing an exception and ignoring it in this case with the condition?

Comment: This is because the try block might fail since it's wrapped in an if statement. So to trigger the fallback alternative we throw an exception to reach the custom alternatives we've predefined in the catch block. All these is to ensure that the trigger method works across multiple browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to fire event using Element method:

```
if (!Element.prototype.triggerEvent) {
    Element.prototype.triggerEvent = function (eventName) {
        var event;

        if (document.createEvent) {
            event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
            event.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
        } else {
            event = document.createEventObject();
            event.eventType = eventName;
        }

        event.eventName = eventName;

        if (document.createEvent) {
            this.dispatchEvent(event);
        } else {
            this.fireEvent("on" + event.eventType, event);
        }
    };
}
```

```js
if (!Element.prototype.triggerEvent) {
    Element.prototype.triggerEvent = function (eventName) {
        var event;

        if (document.createEvent) {
            event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
            event.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
        } else {
            event = document.createEventObject();
            event.eventType = eventName;
        }

        event.eventName = eventName;

        if (document.createEvent) {
            this.dispatchEvent(event);
        } else {
            this.fireEvent("on" + event.eventType, event);
        }
    };
}

var input = document.getElementById("my_input");
var button = document.getElementById("my_button");

input.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    alert('change event fired');
});
button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    input.value = "Bye World";
    input.triggerEvent("change");
});
```

```html
<input id="my_input" type="input" value="Hellow World">
<button id="my_button">Change Input</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

HTML

```
<a href="demoLink" id="myLink"> myLink </a>
<button onclick="fireLink(event)"> Call My Link </button>
```

JS

```
// click event listener of the link element --------------  
document.getElementById('myLink').addEventListener("click", callLink);
function callLink(e) {
    // code to fire
}

// function invoked by the button element ----------------
function fireLink(event) {                   
    document.getElementById('myLink').click();      // script calls the "click" event of the link element 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use jquery event call.
Write the below line where you want to trigger onChange of any element.

```
$("#element_id").change();
```

*element_id* is the ID of the element whose onChange you want to trigger.

Avoid the use of

```
 element.fireEvent("onchange");
```

Because it has very less support. Refer this document for its [support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/fireEvent).

Answer (score -11):

What you want is something like this:

```
document.getElementByClassName("example").click();
```

Using jQuery, it would be something like this:

```
$(".example").trigger("click");
```

Comment: trigger method is not wrong, but it is a jquery method

Comment: 1. `document.getElementByClassName` doesn't exist.
2. `document.getElementsByClassName` exist but returns a list.
3. this only works for a select few native events.
4. The last example triggers a jQuery event where no underlying native event exists.