# how to trigger a mouse click event using javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I trigger a JavaScript event click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click)

I am developing a website, i want to trigger a mouse click event to a button using java script. please can any one help me solve this problem.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

```
document.getElementById('your_button').click();
```

Comment: This is not cross-browser compatible. Afaik this only works in Firefox.

Comment: `element.onclick();` is cross browser afaiks.

Comment: thanks for your reply Felix Kling. the above script is to trigger button click event not mouse click event..

Comment: @Arun: Well, the click event triggers the click event handler. Calling the handler is sufficient in most of the cases. If you need something else you have to more specific.

Comment: thanks for your reply caffein. what are you specifying as "element" in your script ?

Comment: @Arun `element = document.getElementById('your_button');`

Comment: onclick does not work for me in latest version of Chrome

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById("id of button").onclick();`

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("theButton").onclick();
```

Here is an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2Vzu/).