# Click on Li via Console Programatically

Tags: javascript, list, function, click

Imagine there is a List item called one. When you click on this List item it opens a new page. I want to click on the List item with a js code input via the google chrome console (without button...).

The id of the Li is: one

```
document.getElementById("one").click();
```

When i put that in the console it doesn´t work.

Comment: are you sure that the event you are looking for is associated to the `li`?

Comment: yes im sure about it

Answer (score 0):

The `.click()` is not cross browser compatible.

Use `.onclick()` instead.

[See related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6582748/how-to-trigger-a-mouse-click-event-using-javascript)

Comment: This does work: here are a few things to verify

1. You are resolving an element from the `document.getElementById("one")` call.
2. You have assigned a click handler... example => `document.getElementById("one").onclick = function() { alert("test") };`