# How to dynamically click a button again once it is clicked (treat a single click as a double click) JavaScript

Tags: javascript, onclick, click

How would I dynamically click a button again once it is clicked once by the user?

For example:

```
<input type='button' value='Click me once, and I will click twice!' onClick='click button again using JavaScript' />
```

So I want to click the button, and have the button click it's self again.

Is this possible, and how would I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: *"So I want to click the button, and have the button click it's self again."* Why? If you tell us what your real goal is, we will almost certainly be able to offer you a better solution.

Comment: So you want the `doubleclick` handlers called? And are you using any libraries? (jQuery, Closure, Prototype, ...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I would like to do this with pure JavaScript. Would the click() function work here?

Comment: @ pattyd: Using a library doesn't mean you're not using "pure" JavaScript. If you mean you don't want to use anything other than the JavaScript functions defined in the spec and the ones provided by the DOM functions, okay. Can you answer the other questions?

Comment: try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click

Comment: @T.J.Crowder looking back at this question 8 years later I am also curious what my actual goal was

Comment: @pattyd - LOL! I've done that. :-D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like this is what you're looking for

HTML

```
<input type='button' value='Click me once, and I will click twice!' onClick='clickclick();' />
```

JS

```
function clickclick(){
    alert("click");
    reclick();
}    
function reclick(){
    alert("reclick");
}
```

working example : http://jsfiddle.net/eQdBY/

---

**EDIT**

to trigger the click behaviour, use onclick:

```
 document.getElementById("btn").onclick();
```

anyway, I think that recalling the button click inside the button onclick event, will take you to an infinite loop, so you should use two separate functions or use a "click counter" to handle that.

example of onclick usage: http://jsfiddle.net/eQdBY/1/

Comment: I don't think that's the question.