# Is it possible to fire a button's ClientClick event from another button's Click Event?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, web-applications, messagebox, onclientclick

I need to display a YesNo messagebox, in case of a server side code execution failure. As far as I can tell, you can't show a messagebox from the server side. Is a walk around of sorts, where I fire a hidden button's OnClientClick Event programmatically in order to display a messagebox is possible? If so, how do I trigger it?
If not, Is there any other way to display a YesNo messagebox from the server side?

As far as I can tell, unless I misunderstood, the solutions I was given or was refered to, handled cases where client side script fires the second button's event, but that's not what I'm looking for. I need the server side script to trigger the client side script/event.

Comment: There's a very good answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click) by [Juan Mendes](http://stackoverflow.com/users/227299/juan-mendes). But if you like to take shortcuts, jQuery has a nice [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method :)

Comment: Do you mean you want to display a winform MedsageBox on the server side so the user can click Yes or No? Or you want to display a client "browser" message then fire an event on the server by using a hidden Asp.Net hidden button control?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery way

```
$('#button1').on('click', function(e){
    $('#button2').trigger('click');
});
```

JavaScript way

```
var button1 = document.getElementById('button1'),
    button2 = document.getElementById('button2');

button1.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    e.initEvent('click', true, false);
    button2.dispatchEvent(e);
});
```