# Javascript pass onclick on child to parent

Tags: javascript, html

I have div (.upload-drop-zone, yellow zone at screenshot) with another div (.dropzone-width, blue zone) inside.

```
<div class="upload-drop-zone dz-clickable" id="drop-zone-600">               
    <div class="dropzone-width">600 PX</div>
</div>
```

[image: uploader]

There is a javascript onclick event attached to .upload-drop-zone (when I click on it, it shows file chooser dialog). Event attached by third-party plugin, so I have no access to function which be called.

The problem is that if I make click on .dropzone-width, click event did not pass to .upload-drop-zone so nothing happens instead of showing file chooser dialog. What can I do to fix it?

P.S.: Sorry for bad english.

Comment: What versions of IE do you need to support?

Comment: @JuanMendes It does not matter, Internet Explorer 10+, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for a click in the inner div and fire the click on the outer div.

```js
$("#drop-zone-600").click(function (e) {
 alert("hey");   
});


$("#dzw").click(function (e) {
    $("#drop-zone-600").onclick();
});
```

```css
.upload-drop-zone {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: darkred;
}

.dropzone-width {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="upload-drop-zone dz-clickable" id="drop-zone-600">               
    <div id ="dzw" class="dropzone-width">600 PX</div>
</div>
```

Despite the fact that the alert function is inside the click event listener of the `#drop-zone-600` div, you can see the alert by clicking any of the divs.

Comment: Note that this works only if the event handler was set using jQuery, for an implementation that works no matter how the event handler was registered, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29237191/227299

Answer (score 27):

Try this, I had a same issue before. No javscript required...

```
.dropzone-width {  pointer-events: none; }
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for non-pointer click events, such as from Enter or Spacebar when the element is focused.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to synthetically fire the click event. See [How can I trigger a JavaScript event click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click/2381862#2381862)

```
fireEvent( document.getElementById('drop-zone-600'), 'click' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this via jquery:

```
$(".dropzone-width").on("click", function(){
   $("#drop-zone-600").trigger("click");
});
```