# click on an image link when a web page is opened using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new in Javascript and this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a href="http://www.example.com" id="test" onclick="example(this); return false"><img src="http://www.example.com/1/img" border="0" /></a> 

 <script>
 function () {
 document.getElementById('test').click();
 };
 function();
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

I was trying to open that link when  the web page is loaded but I make some errors. Any help?

Comment: Open console and check errors. After that remove meaningless `function() {}` and `function()`. Leave only `document.getElementById('test').click();`. Or if you *really*  want immediate anonymous function (although you don't need it in your case), use `(function() { document.getElementById('test').click(); })()`.

Comment: Doesn't look like `example()` is defined...

Comment: @dfsq Thanks buddy really helpfull. Can you please answer me here so that I can check this thread as solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you define and invoke function is not correct. This is invalid syntax construction as [function declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#The_function_declaration_(function_statement)) (statement staring with `function` keyword) requires a name to be valid javascript code.

So you either give function a name an invoke it:

```
function somename() {
    document.getElementById('test').click();
};
somename();
```

.. or use [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (immediately-invoked function expression):

```
(function() {
    document.getElementById('test').click();
})();
```

However, in your case you don't really need as you don't use it for what it's really useful, i.e. creating new scope. Simple line

```
document.getElementById('test').click();
```

would be just enough.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the example function... remove `onclick="example(this)..."`. Since you are clicking via javascript, the normal function of the click is to go to the link specified in the `href` attribute anyway.

If you just want to open a new link on page load, you can also remove all the body and just use the following:

```
<body>
    <script>
        window.location.assign = "http://example.com";
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a href="http://www.example.com" id="test" onclick="yourfunction()">asdf</a> 

 <script>
   
 document.getElementById('test').onclick();
   
   function yourfunction(){
     alert("clicked");
   }

 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

What we do here is assigning the function "yourfunction()" to "onclick" of your anchor (the  element). Due to the fact that your code is automatically executed when you reload the page (note that we've just posted a line of code into the script tag) you can trigger the onclick event just by using ".onclick()".

However, you're executing "yourfunction()" every time you reload the page and as you click your anchor.

The function itself is pretty boring. It just makes an alert (small window with a message and ok button) which says "clicked".

Further reading:

- [How can I trigger a JavaScript event click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick
- https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/alert

Some further advice. I think you are trying to achieve a "redirection" to another site as soon as you got to a domain. You probably want to do stuff like redirecting a typo ("gogole.com") to your "real" domain (google.com). This shouldn't be done with Javascript! You have to configure your webserver to do so (it's pretty easy). See [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/344614/simple-apache2-redirect-from-one-domain-to-another) for example.

However, ther is also another approach to achieve this:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.example.com/">
```

Put this line of code into the  of your document.