# click element on mouseover function not working

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

hi i have a code that i want to autoplay some youtube videos in any device.the problem is that in mobile devices both android and ios the autoplay events are been disabled. so i want to create a function that will click the iframe.
the code i have is the below

```
<iframe id="text" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5-RszQzQCvg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>


<form>
  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onmouseover="myFunction()">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("text").click();}
</script>
```

the problem is that when i mouseover the checkbox my function dosent work because the video dosent start.

Comment: Check answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click

Comment: i have checked but it is not working either.

Comment: `#text` is the `iframe` element on your main page, it's not the video within the iframe. Clicking on the `iframe` element would be  pretty much the same as clicking the frame border.

Comment: is it possible to click the video in the iframe?

Comment: No, it is not possible (cross-domain access is denied). You need [YT JS Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference).

Comment: thank you i will give it a try. but will this work on mobile devices?

Comment: It's not possible to autoplay videos on mobile devices. This is by design to protect the users, because videos require high amounts of data which is usually expensive on mobile connections.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to simulate clicks to simulate videos autoplay in ios devices. Even though you could find a workaround this behavior is by design, so the workaround would likely be fixed.

It is explained in this Apple developer document:

https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html