# how to click an anchor tag from javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Have an anchor tag, trying to click it from the javascript but not responding, while loading the page it should go to `next.php` without click anchor tag manually.how can I archive this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         alert("hai");
         $(document).ready(function() { $('#about').click(); });             
    </script>
</head>   
<body>
    <div>
         <a href="next.php" id="about">click here</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use `$('selector')[0]`, as `$('selector')` returns a jQuery object, so `$('selector').click()` will fire the click handler, while `$('selector')[0].click()` would fire the actual click.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#about')[0].click();  //$('#about').get(0).click();
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/erfv3wu2/1/)**

Comment: shall i know why `[0]` after id? what is `get(0)`?

Comment: `get(0)` is same as `[0]`. *Why`[0]` after `id`* because- `$('#about')` returns a *jQuery* object. So a click event on this will fire a jQuery click handler, if defined. `$('#about')[0]` will return a *javascript* object and `click()` on this will simulate actual click.

Comment: It worked for me. Anyway I could not understand the concept of "will fire the click handler, while ***** would fire actual click."

Comment: @ShaunakD Thanks bro searching for this for a long time

Answer (score 3):

You can not use javascript to fire click event

It should use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() { 
             document.location.href='/next.php'
       });
</script>
```

Comment: *You can not use javascript to fire click event* - You can http://stackoverflow.com/q/2381572/3639582.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that can help you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').trigger('click');
  });

})

function abc() {
  alert("");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="abc()">click me not</a>
```

If you want the recommended way then use this inside $(document).ready

```
window.location="where ever you want to go";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the page to go to `next.php` without clicking then place the `window.location` directly into `$(document).ready(function() { });`

`Click()` function is used when you want to trigger click event. ie. when you want to trigger some action when anchor tag is clicked.

```
<script>
   alert("hai");
   $(document).ready(function() { 
      window.location = 'next.php';  //If you wish the page to automatically go to next page on page load.
      $('#about').click(   // If you wish to do something clicking anchor
        function(){
           alert("Hello");
        }); 
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() { $('#about').trigger('click'); });
```

Updated:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {  $('#about')[0].click(); });
```

Comment: no respond for this code, it shows normal, after click only it goes next page.