# Javascript Event Listener - "change" value set by Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a process designed to change concatenate separate address fields entered by a user into a single hidden field to be used by Google Maps to drop a pin on the location.

The Event Listeners responsible for the concatenation are functioning properly, but when I try to chain a listener to the hidden field to execute the pin placement, the function isn't executed.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function initMap() {

    ...

    function join_address() {
        var address = document.getElementById('id_form5-address1').value;
        var city = document.getElementById('id_form5-city').value;
        var state = document.getElementById('id_form5-state').value;
        var zip = document.getElementById('id_form5-zip').value;
        document.getElementById('id_jointAddress').value = address+", "+city+", "+state+", "+zip;
        }

    document.getElementById("id_form5-city").addEventListener("change", join_address);
    document.getElementById("id_form5-state").addEventListener("change", join_address);
    document.getElementById("id_form5-zip").addEventListener("change", join_address);

    function codeAddress() {
        console.log("function engaged")
        var address = document.getElementById("id_jointAddress").value;
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
          } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
          }
        });
      }

    document.getElementById("id_jointAddress").addEventListener("change", codeAddress);

    ...

}
```

"Function engaged" never even prints to console, so I am assuming that it is the listener that is constructed wrong, or is in the wrong place. Can anyone assist?

Edit: Here is the html object in question:

`<input type="hidden" name="jointAddress" id="id_jointAddress">`

If I unhide the element, and type in the field directly it triggers the listener. I think the "change" listener does not respond to changes made through Javascript. Does anyone know of a solution that will work for me?

Comment: what type of object is `#id_jointAddress?`

Comment: Did it return you html object _document.getElementById("id_jointAddress")_?

Comment: Mind providing an example? [It seems to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/ofyo6rtk/).

Comment: it looks like you're wrapping everything in the function `initMap()` is that ever called?

Comment: I added the html object that I am using. The other event listeners are functioning, I'm not sure why this final one is not working.

Comment: @AdamStarrh "added" as in added dynamically after the DOM or page loaded? If so you want to delegate the even using jQuery's `.on("change", codeAddress)`.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into learning some jQuery if I can't get the javascript to work.

Comment: setting `input.value === "Hello"` does not fire handlers. Handlers only fire when the user manually changes input values. See http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/uct8bL9d/ If you want to fire events programatically, use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click/2381862#2381862

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that setting `value` programatically doesn't fire the change event. You can fire a [synthetic event on your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click/2381862#2381862). See http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/uct8bL9d/2/

If you use the [`fireEvent` function I linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click/2381862#2381862), you can just add the following line in your code

```
var joint = document.getElementById('id_jointAddress');   
joint.value = address + ", " + city + ", " + state + ", " + zip;
fireEvent(joint, 'change');
```

Here's a reduction of the problem:

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', function() {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML +='changed <br />'; 
});

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var input =  document.querySelector('input');
    input.value = new Date();
    fireEvent(input, 'change')
});

/**
 * Fire an event handler to the specified node. Event handlers can detect that the event was fired programatically
 * by testing for a 'synthetic=true' property on the event object
 * @param {HTMLNode} node The node to fire the event handler on.
 * @param {String} eventName The name of the event without the "on" (e.g., "focus")
 */
function fireEvent(node, eventName) {
    // Make sure we use the ownerDocument from the provided node to avoid cross-window problems
    var doc;
    if (node.ownerDocument) {
        doc = node.ownerDocument;
    } else if (node.nodeType == 9){
        // the node may be the document itself, nodeType 9 = DOCUMENT_NODE
        doc = node;
    } else {
        throw new Error("Invalid node passed to fireEvent: " + node.id);
    }

     if (node.dispatchEvent) {
        // Gecko-style approach (now the standard) takes more work
        var eventClass = "";

        // Different events have different event classes.
        // If this switch statement can't map an eventName to an eventClass,
        // the event firing is going to fail.
        switch (eventName) {
            case "click": // Dispatching of 'click' appears to not work correctly in Safari. Use 'mousedown' or 'mouseup' instead.
            case "mousedown":
            case "mouseup":
                eventClass = "MouseEvents";
                break;

            case "focus":
            case "change":
            case "blur":
            case "select":
                eventClass = "HTMLEvents";
                break;

            default:
                throw "fireEvent: Couldn't find an event class for event '" + eventName + "'.";
                break;
        }
        var event = doc.createEvent(eventClass);

        var bubbles = eventName == "change" ? false : true;
        event.initEvent(eventName, bubbles, true); // All events created as bubbling and cancelable.

        event.synthetic = true; // allow detection of synthetic events
        // The second parameter says go ahead with the default action
        node.dispatchEvent(event, true);
    } else  if (node.fireEvent) {
        // IE-old school style
        var event = doc.createEventObject();
        event.synthetic = true; // allow detection of synthetic events
        node.fireEvent("on" + eventName, event);
    }
};
```

```html
<input />
<button>Set programatically</button>

<div id="output"> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that setting value programatically doesn't fire the change handlers. If you use jQuery and call `val()`, then it will fire a synthetic change event. Try updating your JavaScript to utilize jQuery.

```
$(function(){
    function initMap() {
        ...
    }

    function join_address() {
        var address = $('#id_form5-address1').val();
        var city = $('#id_form5-city').val();
        var state = $('#id_form5-state').val();
        var zip = $('#id_form5-zip').val();
        $('#id_jointAddress').val(address+", "+city+", "+state+", "+zip);
    }

    $("#id_form5-city").on("change", join_address);
    $("#id_form5-state").on("change", join_address);
    $("#id_form5-zip").on("change", join_address);

    function codeAddress() {
        console.log("function engaged")
        var address = $("#id_jointAddress").val();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
          } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
          }
        });
      }

    $("#id_jointAddress").on("change", codeAddress);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried making these changes, but it broke it further. I'm not really used to jQuery. If I can't find an easy javascript solution, I will try harder to implement this change.

Comment: let me know if you have any interest in implementing jQuery, I can help you through the errors you're getting

Comment: I tried this again and got the page working, but it seems to be stuck in the same spot. The `join_address` function executes successfully, but the `codeAddress` function is never called.