# Auto trigger button action instead pressing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have someone done the below aspx file

Right now the button action need manually triggered by pressing "search" button, I want to achieve that button page to be automatically trigger the action itself without needing person to clicked it, how to I accomplish this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/CheckBookingApp.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSearch").CheckBooking();
    })
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <button id="btnSearch">Search</button>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: So if you don't want it done under the button press, when do you want it to happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I trigger a JavaScript event click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click)

Comment: Will it submit the button continuously or just once when the page loads ?

Comment: That button actually trigger a popup within the page itself

Comment: But when does it trigger, if not on the user click ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can trigger a "simulated click" event by javascript `$('btnSearch').trigger('click');`

if you wish to incorporate a time delay you can use `setTimeout()`

in your example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSearch").CheckBooking();
    setTimeout(function() { 
           $("#btnSearch").trigger('click');
        }, 5000 /* 5000ms = 5sec */);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call your checkBooking() function inside your domready.

You can have it so the popup is displayd when the button is clicked as well.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {

  function checkBooking() {
    alert('Checking booking');
  }

  // when the page loads
  checkBooking();
    
  //when the button is pressed
  $("#btnSearch").on('click', function() {
    checkBooking();
  });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <button id="btnSearch">Check booking</button>
</form>
```