# angular2 test, how to test event is bound to an element

Tags: unit-testing, angular, components

I am writing an angular2 unit test for a component.
With fully using JQuery it's possible to find what event is bound to an element. However in Angular2, I am not sure it's possible or not

For example, the following code has a click event, which is a public function of a component

```
      <button (click)="doLogin()" [disabled]="myDisabled">Login</button>
```

By reading DOM element, I can make it sure all properties and data binding is correct by running a test. Only thing that I don't know is, "`event` binding is correct or not" because the generated html is like the following

```
      <button>Login</button>
```

I want to make it sure someone does not delete this event binding in the future by writing a test for it.

In summary, how do I know event is properly bound to DOM element?

EDIT: 
Is there a way to know there is click event without actually clicking it?

Comment: Why don't you test that the function inside is called? If it is not, you can assume that somebody removed it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the approach below (calling the `click`:

```
it('should render list', injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
  return tcb.createAsync(MyList).then((componentFixture: ComponentFixture) => {
    const element = componentFixture.nativeElement;
    componentFixture.detectChanges();
    expect(element.querySelectorAll('li').length).toBe(5);
    document.getElementById('test').click();
  });
}));
```

See this question for more details:

- [How can I trigger a JavaScript event click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click)

Comment: Is there a way to know there is click event without clicking it? I might be wrong to ask this approach instead of triggering click event.