# angular2 unit test: how to test events with triggerEventHandler

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I'm trying to write a unit test for `click` event with angular2 **rc1**. my component handles click event with `onClick()` method and changes `name` field from `bar` to `foo`. see this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VLSjLOwbzR9AaVd2ioHE?p=preview).

Now I want to fire a `click` event to test whether `name` value is `bar` or not. please see `unit-testing.spec.ts` file on plunker.

```
it('should change name from foo to bar on click event', inject([], () => {
return builder.createAsync(UnitTestingComponentTestController)
  .then((fixture: ComponentFixture<any>) => {
    let query = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(UnitTestingComponent));
    expect(query).toBeTruthy();
    expect(query.componentInstance).toBeTruthy();

    // fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(query.componentInstance.name).toBe('foo');
    query.triggerEventHandler('click',{});
    expect(query.componentInstance.name).toBe('bar');
    // fixture.detectChanges();
  });
}));
```

And here is `UnitTestingComponentTestController`

```
@Component({
selector: 'test',
template: `
<app-unit-testing></app-unit-testing>
`,
directives: [UnitTestingComponent]
})
class UnitTestingComponentTestController {
}
```

This test fails with this message:

```
Expected 'foo' to be 'bar'.
```

Here is the method signature for `triggerEventHandler()`

```
triggerEventHandler(eventName: string, eventObj: any): void;
```

**My question is how can I fire an event and test it with angular2.**

One solution might be to call `onClick()` method on `componentInstance` but in this case we just test **internal** of the class and not the **component behavior**

Answer (score 12):

After reading [this](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/testing-angular-2-components-unit-tests-testcomponentbuilder/) article, now I can trigger click event inside my test. This approach doesn't use `triggerEventHandler`. If your template is something like this:

```
<div class="my-class" (click)="onClick()">
  <ul id="my-id">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

you can use `fixture.nativeElement.querySelector(<your selector>).click()` to trigger click event on **selected** element. this approach calls javascript `click()` function (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36039168/angular2-test-how-to-test-event-is-bound-to-an-element))

You can select element based on its `id`, `class` or path (xpath?). For example:

```
fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.my-class').click()
```

or

```
fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#my-id').click()
```

or

```
fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('div>ul>li').click()
```

Comment: Can u post the full test case please?

Comment: I answered it a year ago. unfortunately I don't have access to this project anymore.

Comment: np, asked a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44616434/how-to-actually-trigger-a-click-event-and-check-the-outcome-in-angular2