# How to actually trigger a click event and check the outcome in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-testing

I want to actually check, that the *selected* attribute has been rendered with a true instead of an undefined.

My working (manually tested) Component functionality:

```
export class PlayerSelectorComponent implements OnInit {

    players: any = []

    ...

    toggleSelectPlayer( player: any ) {
        if (player.selected) {
            player.selected = false
        }
        else {
            player.selected = true
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the template:

```
 <ul class="list-group">
     <player-row *ngFor="let player of players"
                 [player]="player"
                 [selected]="player.selected"
                 (click) = "toggleSelectPlayer(player)">
     </player-row>
 </ul>
```

Here is the test code:

```
it( 'should render a player as selected after a user clicks on the player row', fakeAsync( () => {
    let player = fixture.debugElement.query( By.css( '.player-row' ) )
    expect( player.attributes.selected ).toBe( undefined )
    player.triggerEventHandler( 'click', null )
    tick()
    fixture.detectChanges()
    player = fixture.debugElement.query( By.css( '.player-row' ) )
    expect( player.attributes.selected ).toBeTruthy() // Expected undefined to be truthy
} ) )
```

**In the last line of the code, you can see, that my tests do not detect that the player.attributes.selected is actually changed after the click. It remains to be undefined..**

Comment: What's the question, or problem?

Comment: sorry, updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're querying css, but not actually manipulating css in anything you posted. You want to test the component variable to be `true`.

After you `fixture.detectChanges()` you're going to want to `expect( component.player.selected ).toBeTruthy()`. This is assuming you have a TestBed for testing.

If you're looking to actually check the "activated" status (not selected) on your bootstrap form-group, then you'll need to apply your `[ngClass]="{'selected':player.selected}"` in your *ngFor loop.

Comment: Absolutely perfect man, tested passed :)

So this requires me to change my mindset - the custom input attributes are not attributes that I create in the DOM, rather some angular 2 inner thingy that I need to grasp :)