# What's the equivalent of this code in pure/native javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<label class="file">File</label>
<input class="none" type="file">
```

jQuery:

```
$('.file').click(function(){ $('.none').click();});
```

Comment: You even no need any js for that equivalent. Your best bet would be just to wrap your input inside label   https://jsfiddle.net/ehp5v1rm/  That's how it should be done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this

```
 var _file = document.getElementsByClassName('file')[0]; //Return a NodeList
_file.onclick = function(){
  document.getElementsByClassName('none')[0].click();
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L2zm6sq9/)

**EDIT**

If there are multiple elements with same class

```
var _file = document.getElementsByClassName('file'); //Return a NodeList
var _none =  document.getElementsByClassName('none');
for(var x = 0;x<_file.length;x++){
  (function(x){   //Creating closure 
   _file[x].addEventListener('click',function(){
   console.log(x)
     document.getElementsByClassName('none')[x].click();
   })
 }(x))
}
```

[Demo2](https://jsfiddle.net/L2zm6sq9/2/)

Comment: What if there are multiple elements having class `file` & `none`.

Comment: OP has not mentioned about multiple class. If it is so then have to loop and add addEventListener

Comment: `$('.none').click();` is the same as `.trigger('click')`, which triggers event on **all** elements. [demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/br3b3ty4/), so You should call `.click()` on all `document.getElementsByClassName('none')` (nested loop)

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection`, not a `NodeList` (there's a big difference when accessing it, also in performance)

Answer (score 0):

This might be the most accurate equivalent:

```
document.querySelector(".file")
    .addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelector(".none").click();
});
```

For a more cross-browser alternative for `.click()`: [How can I trigger a JavaScript event click](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2381572/3393058)