# how to simulate button click from a page to another page with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, button, click, html

Can Javascript simulate button click from a page to another page both pages are in same domain.
I need to click a button then get the webpage's content. Any hints?

I have tried

```
var newwin = window.open('somelink');

var xy = newwin.document.getElementbyId('id');
```

Comment: sure, if both pages are on the same domain. otherwise that's called cross site scripting and is frowned upon and not possible in most situations.

Comment: yes they both are on the same domain . what i have to do to solve the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I trigger a JavaScript event click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click)

Comment: Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/kpduncan/h47k5gfk/