# How to trigger click event

Tags: html, dom, dom-events, elm

In simple html + js applications when I need to open dialogues of some interactive input elements (such as `input[type="file"]` or `input[type="date"]` or `input[type="color"]`) any non-standard way (with a button or on page load) the most strait forward way is to [trigger `click` event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click) on above mentioned elements. But I couldn't find a way to do that in pure elm (without ports). I see for DOM events manipulation there is [`focus` trigger](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/dom/1.1.1/Dom#focus), but no `click`. Am I missing something? Is it not the "elm way" of doing things?

Comment: Elm can not trigger DOM Events, it's not intended to be used for low-level DOM manipulations by design. Use ports or consider changing something in your architecture.

Comment: think carefully about your design here, as only Chrome has a date picker widget built in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading throught the MDN on `File` element I saw they suggest to use `<label>` to trigger the element without `JavaScript`:

```
<input type="file" id="fileElem" multiple accept="image/*" style="display:none" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
<label for="fileElem">Select some files</label>
```

[elm-fileinput](https://github.com/lovasoa/elm-fileinput)https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Found a library for `<input type="file">`: https://github.com/lovasoa/elm-fileinput.

Also I have put up a working example using the decoder from this lib: https://runelm.io/c/ie0.

Answer (score 3):

You can (ab)use the way `Html.attribute` can take an arbitrary string (i.e. `Html.attribute "onclick" "javascript:someFunction(this)"`). In *some* cases, this is reasonable since it can provide the least amount friction. For example, if you're wanting a button that focuses a hidden file input, and it's wrapped up nicely in a component/view file that where it's always a button followed by a file input, this makes sense:

```
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes as Attr exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (on)


filePick : Html msg
filePick =
    div [ class "file-pick-wrapper" ]
        [ button 
            [ type_ "button"
            , attribute "onclick" "javascript:this.nextElementSibling.click()" 
            ] 
            [ text "Choose a File" ]
        , input
            [ type_ "file"
            , on "change" someMsgDecoder
            , style [ ( "display", "none" ) ]
            ]
            []
        ]
```

From there you can have the `someMsgDecoder` use `Json.Decode` to read `at [ "target", "files", "0", "name" ]` for the filename.