# How to make a form able to upload files in elm

Tags: forms, file-upload, elm

I am trying to make a form in elm that would be able to upload a picture and some accompanying data.

Right now all my fields are updating my model via the `onInput` function, and I when I press the submit button I send my data as JSON via the `Http.post` function. If I understand well this is the idiomatic way of doing forms in elm.

Is there a way to add file uploading capabilities to this kind of form? If possible I would like to keep control in the elm app without resorting to the standard html elements to do submitting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you are. Some of my notes:

- http://simonh1000.github.io/2016/12/elm-s3-uploads/

  - https://github.com/simonh1000/file-reader
- https://github.com/danyx23/elm-dropzone

  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/File_drag_and_drop
- [File Upload in Elm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329962/file-upload-in-elm)
- [elm: read file content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41344662/elm-read-file-content)
- https://www.paramander.com/blog/using-ports-to-deal-with-files-in-elm-0-17
- Add support for  https://github.com/elm-lang/html/issues/20

  - https://github.com/lovasoa/elm-fileinput
- https://www.reddit.com/r/elm/comments/4926am/uploading_files_through_elmhttp/
- http://elm-ui.info/documentation/guides/handling-files
- [How to trigger click event in elm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41332186/how-to-trigger-click-event-in-elm)

Comment: I haven't read everything in detail yet, but do I have to use native-code?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, native code is needed for two things:

- to access the FileReader API; and
- to 'trick' the HTTP library into allowing you to add a file to a multipart form.

This is all covered in [this blog post](http://simonh1000.github.io/2016/12/elm-s3-uploads/), which accompanies the FileReader library mentioned by rofol.

Instead of native code, you can of course use ports.