# How to activate an <a> element on a web page with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to click on this element.

```
<a href="/game.php?vil=9&amp;screen=settings&amp;action=sitter_login&amp;player=305&amp;h=417c13fb" target="_blank" class="btn">ini</a>
```

There are other elements, just like that where only the href changes. I can correctly find the  element I want. But cannot click it...
I tried the usual click() but didn't work:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[1].click()
```

Any help?

I tried this, it opens the same window, but I want to open in a new tab. I also put the internet option to open tabs with popups:

```
b=document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[1].href;
window.location.assign(b, '_blank');
```

How to open in new tab? I tried window.open() but never got to make it work:

```
window.open(b, '_blank');
```

Comment: I think all you try is OK. Just, browsers tends to block to open new tabs and usually adds a _small_ warning on the top of the window. Check the permissions for your site about to open new tabs. Usually there is a special icon on the address bar.

Comment: Your last example will work in response to a user-generated event, but see @Syscall's point above. You're probably being blocked by the browser's popup blocker.

Comment: How can I check that? I'm using chrome

Comment: Got it. Thank you @Syscall

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer here [How can I trigger a JavaScript event click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click). If you execute the .click() function, you trigger all the listener that are bind on the 'click' ( .onClick ).
Try to listen for the click event and then execute the .click() function

Comment: If the answer is on SO, don't post an answer. Instead, when you have enough rep, post a comment pointing to the answer; and later than that, when you have enough rep, vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @MarcoPredari , its not my webpage, I can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure i understand the question all the way. But when you actually click a link all other JavaScripts stops loading and you get to that webpage. The window.open is right. But you have to prevent the Url to actually redirect you to the website. You can do this by using preventDefault on the eventobject that fires on your click. Hope this helps

```js
let myLink = document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[1];

myLink.addEventListener('click', function newWindow(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  window.open(this.href, '_blank')
}) 
  myLink.click();
```