# Javascript : click() on link doesn't click the link and shows undefined

Tags: javascript

I have link with below properties (class and title only) on my webpage :

```
<li class="wux-layouts-treeview-label" title="Shared with me">Shared with me</li>
```

I am trying below code for link in Javascript:

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("wux-layouts-treeview-label")[2];
a.click()
```

result shows `undefined`.

also when I checked `events` available for this link with the code :

`getEventListeners(a)`, it shows blank `{}`

Please help me to click on this link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I trigger a JavaScript event click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click)

Comment: Add `console.log(a)` and check to make sure it returns an element. Can you show us some more of your code as well?

Comment: @Lanchan Walls: I am getting value of "a" as <li class="wux-layouts-treeview-label" title="Shared with me">Shared with me</li>, but when I use a.click() -> it shows "undefined"

Comment: Have you added an event listener to that element? If so, what should run when it is clicked?

Comment: Yes i tried to add the "click" event using the code a.addEventListener("click",function(e){e.preventDefualt();console.log('clicked')}). Correct me in case.

Comment: Try: `<li class="wux-layouts-treeview-label" title="Shared with me" onclick="console.log('clicked')">Shared with me</li>` and that should definitely output.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. Still getting output as "clicked" and then "undefined". The output was as below : a.onclick()
clicked
undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("wux-layouts-treeview-label");
for (var i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].onclick = function(){
        alert("Finaly!");
    }
    }
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do? Obviously it adds listeners to all the elements, but why would OP want that?