# Is there a way to click the button without "onclick" field in the webpage using chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to click a button in webpage using chrome extension. The DOM of the button is as below:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-start" id="start">Download</button>
```

I got the DOM information from chrome panel (F12). It does not have a field of "onclick". Is that means I could not click it by script? I could only click it by mouse? Thank you for any explaination.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I trigger a JavaScript event click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click)

Comment: `document.getElementById('start').click(); `

Comment: Or assign and then click 
`const myButton = document.getElementById('start');`
`myButton.click();`