# Fill data into Office 365 Excel Form with JavaScript (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, query-string

I'm new in JavaScript and wish to create something that can help my company to do some automated work.

I am creating a chrome extension to trace time in motion of my colleagues dairy work on the browser.

Basically the chrome extension will capture `userName` and click event and submitting to Office 365 Excel form by using URL Query String `window.open(URL&userName)` and `setAttributes("Value", userName)` then `getElementbyId("button").click()` to submit the form, but it unable to pass thru as the value will be reset and error will show "the answer is required"
Anything I missed out?

`document.getElementsByClassName("office-form-question-textbox office-form-textfield-input form-control border-no-radius")[0].setAttribute("value","CCC")`
`document.getElementsByClassName("button-content")[7].click()`

these are 2 line code i ran in javascript.
[ExcelFrom Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJjuu.jpg)

I found [solution for Google Form to silent submission](https://bionicteaching.com/silent-submission-of-google-forms/).and i wish to make it work with Office 365 Excel Form.

Thanks.

Comment: I think, you need check docs on click events/trigger

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click

Comment: Thank for your comment. I able to do a element.click() in console if I manually type in the answer. But it not work if I ran it with setAttribute("value", answer).

Comment: wow you got lot of classnames, use only 1 or call by name

Comment: this is only way i can think of to getEelement and setAttribute(value). there is no name for excel form like google form.