# Create class to handle click and other events of element

Tags: javascript, class, events

I want to create class and want to pass my element to it and fire events form class instead of triggering from javascript events everytime.

My try

HTML :

> ```
> <div id="upload-container">
> <label for="myfile">Select a file:</label>
> <input type="file" id="fileInput" name="myfile">
> <button id="send"> Upload </button> </div>
> ```

Javascript class :

```
function Myevents(ele) {
    this.element = ele;
}

Myevents.prototype = {

    init: function() {
        this.element.addEventListener('click', function(file) {
            console.log(file)
        }(this.element));

        this.element.addEventListener('mouseover', function(file) {
            console.log(file)
        }(this.element));
    }
}

var ele = document.getElementById('send');
var instance = new Myevents(ele);
instance.init();

instance.click() ;  // should be able to call it manually
instance.mouseover();   // should be able to call it manually
```

here both above two calls are not firing as required, how to handle this ,any help would appreciated.

Comment: Why downvote can you please explain?

Comment: Hi, what do you want to achieve exactly, if you want to trigger the click event see [Trigger click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click) So you would instance.element.click()

Comment: No that does't work, that is what the problem is?

Comment: There is no click function inside your prototype

Comment: @ankabot as we can add eventListeners on elements, same thing i want to achieve it from my class, just want to know why my click and mouse events doesn't fire

Comment: @SajeebAhamed I'm adding click listner on init method to the element itself.

Comment: I tested your code you have errors, you shouldn't put `;` after the init method definition, and also there is no `getElementBy` method, use `getElementById`

Comment: @ankabot Corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I recreate your `Myevents` function. I make a `click function` as a prototype and attach click event listener and call it implicitly.

```js
const Myevents = function(el) {
 this.element = el;
}

Myevents.prototype = {
 click: function() {
     // Attach the event listener
     this.element.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
         e.preventDefault();
            console.log('clicked');
        });
        
        // Finally fire the click
        // this.element.click();
    }
}

const el = document.querySelector('#clickbtn');
const instance = new Myevents(el);
instance.click();
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <button id="clickbtn">Ok</button>
</div>
```

Note: I don't know but let me know if it fulfills your requirement.

Comment: Thank you, but why clicked is logging on init time ?

Comment: It's just for showing you. Just remove the ```this.element.click()``` line will allow you to work as usual.

Comment: Check it now. It works after clicking on the ```ok``` button.