# How to find an html element that matches all keywords?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-parsing

I'm writing a bot-like chrome extension for myself and one of it's functions is to parse a random site for a specific html element that contains all keywords provided by user in custom order and `.click()` it. I can't do neither of those.

I played around with jQuery's `:contains` selector a bit and found out that commands like the one i provided below only work for a predefined amount of keywords.

As for `.click()` problem. For some reason it does not work in my case. This looks strange to me because at the same time '.remove()' works perfectly fine.

**Here is my '.js' file responsible for what i'm trying to achieve:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('ready');
    findItem();
});

function findItem() {
    chrome.storage.local.get("settings", function (data) {
        //var newWindow = window.open('SOME SITE URL', 'single');

    if (data.settings.keyWords) {
        
        //code piece that makes an array out of keywords string
        //stored in chrome storage and removes empty elements
        let pkString = data.settings.keyWords;
        const pkArr = pkString.split(", ");
        Object.keys(pkArr).forEach(pk => {
            if (pkArr[pk] == "") {
                pkArr.pop();
                console.log('popped');
            } else {
                console.log(`'${pkArr[pk]}'`);
            }
        });

        if (pkArr) {
            //i basically need something like that but for random amount of keywords
            $(`div:contains("${pkArr[0]}"):contains("${pkArr[1]}"):contains("${pkArr[2]}"):contains("${pkArr[3]}"):contains( ... )`).click();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map over each keyword and compose this into a single selector like so:

```js
$(`div${pkArr.map(keyword => `:contains("${keyword}")`).join('')}`).click();
```

You probably also want to check if there is at least 1 element in the `pkArr`, otherwise, it will match all `<div/>` elements on the page.

As for the `click()` part, this can be caused by multiple reasons. Either the element is not the correct element or it doesn't have a click event listener attached. Not really sure, but it could also be prevented by the browser.

Comment: No, my selector is right. I'm trying to find the exact element that matches all of user's  keywords. The main problem is to make a search  command that can take custom amount of keywords

Comment: It seems to work perfectly fine, thanks a log, think i'll accept the answer. Can you please briefly explain the logic behind the selector you wrote ? Now it looks a bit cryptic to me. 

And as for click() thing. Assuming it is not the browser, what cant i try to make it work?

Comment: You have an Array with the keywords. By using `Array#map`, the keywords are being composed to a selector string. So each Array element now will contain `:contains(keyword)`. Finally, all elements are combined using `Array#join` using an empty  string. This concatenates all elements without any delimiter. For more information about click events, look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click).