# Is there anyway to fire an element's onClick event manually with inspect element?

Tags: javascript

There is a button on an website which used to be clickable,however it is currently not, but it's onClick event is still intact. Is it possible to trigger this event?
[image: picture for reference]

Comment: This should point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I trigger a JavaScript event click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381572/how-can-i-trigger-a-javascript-event-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can right-click the element, click use in console, and add a .click() after the variable it should have auto-filled.

[image: Right-click menu]

[image: Console with .click() call]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seems to be the correct method, as I tested it with the other buttons in the site, but it seems that this specific function must read something from remote server and therefore it has been disabled from there.

Answer (score 0):

In the console, select the button and use `dispatchEvent()` like this:

```
document.querySelector('.property.change').dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))
```